# Execute revert event at draggable element when dropped it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-droppable

I have a problem with jQueryUI and the draggable/droppable options.

What I want to accomplished is this:

1) Drag an element into another one
2) Once the element its there, revert the draggable element to its initial state (and do some other stuff)

I can revert the object to its initial state by doing this:

```
revert : function(event, ui) {
      B(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
          top: 0,
          left: 0
      };
      return !event;
}
```

But I want to revert the element even and when it is dragged into the correct place...

**EDIT**

I have tried this:

```
B('#template').find('section').droppable({
  drop : function(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.triggerHandler('revert');
  }
}
```

But it is not working... I have also tried to get the option and execute it, but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to revert, just `return true` in your revert function

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. Is there any documentation about it? I couldn't find anything in the documentation at jqueyrui, actually, I found the revert event googling for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert

you actually don't need to define the anonymous function...you can just set the revert option to true.

$("#dragme").draggable({revert:true})